# Perl: RegEx: ManyLines: Store text between start and end in an array

Tags: regex, perl

I'm developing a Perl script and one of the script functions is to detect many lines of data between two terminals and store them in an array.

```
my @statistics_of_layers_var;
for( <ALL_FILE> ) {
   @statistics_of_layers_var = ($slurp =~ /(Statistics\s+Of\s+Layers)(\n|.)*(Summary)/gm );
   print @statistics_of_layers_var;
```

The given data should be

```
Statistics Of Layers
Line#1
Line#2
Line#3
Summary
```

In this piece of code, code successfully prints **Statistics Of Layers** and **Summary** but it fails to print all data between those two terminals.

How could I fix this issue?

Comment: Would you mind putting in the other statements that go before the loop in order to setup ALL_FILE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(Statistics\s+Of\s+Layers)((?:\n|.)*)(Summary)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/7

Comment: Yes, this works. Amazing, thanks a lot. Could you guide me what is the function of `?:` ?

Comment: @EslamSaad `?:` means non capturing group.It will be a part of match but will not be stored in an `$1,$2,$3` etc .

Comment: what if I need each line to be stored as `$1,$2,$3`?

Comment: @EslamSaad if the no of lines is a variable that is difficult to achieve.You can ask a new question nonetheless